# Need Android or Iphone mobile devices back button click event in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, knockout.js

Currently working on Single Page Application(HTML5) using following plugins :
- Sammy.js
- Knockout.js
- Require.js
- Jquery.js

This application is developed for Android, Iphone & Windows mobile devices, lot of scenarios are based on click of device back button or browser back button, can anybody have idea how to handle device back button or browser back button click event?
As this is SPA framework, hence navigation happen on route hash change which is handle by Sammy.js, but on every navigation sammy.before event is called and not able to distinguish between the browser back or device back or its simple navigation.

Comment: Did you tried answer ??

Answer (score 0):

Use code below

```
class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void loginReady() {
    ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WebView wv = (WebView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.webView);
            wv.loadUrl("javascript:setDeviceInfo('" + CommonUtilities.deviceInfo(mContext) + "');");
        }
    });
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void exitApp() {
    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}
}
```

In Your activity add JavaScriptInterface and override onBackPressed

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:goBack();");
}
```

In Your JavaScript

```
function goBack() {
 Android.exitApp();
}
```